# Javascript round decimal

Tags: javascript

I need to round **6.300000000000001** to **6.31**. How to do it?

```js
console.log(6.300000000000001.toFixed(2)); // returns 6.30
```

Comment: Use `Math.ceil(number * 100) / 100)`?

Comment: 6.300000000000001 rounds to 6.30 .... 6.305000000000001 rounds to 6.31